# Missing "Easy Mode" from Samsung Galaxy Core Prime

Tags: samsung, settings, user-interface

I bought this phone for my grandparents. The salesman at the store told me that this phone would be great for old people who are new to smart phones. Any idea where to find this "Easy Mode" or "Simple Mode" option? There's no such option under Settings.

Model: SM-G361F

Android version: 5.1.1

Comment: Can you provide the screenshot of the setting? The feature should be there under "Personal" section ([Verizon manual](http://www.verizonwireless.com/support/samsung-galaxy-core-prime-easy-mode-video/))

Comment: How do I do that? I tried this: http://www.samsung.com/us/support/answer/ANS00032055/253232/. I got two of the phones. The settings under Personal are: "Accounts", "Backup and reset", "Accessibility". I've scanned through all the menues, there's no such option.

Comment: You may have already tried this but in the settings are you able to search for stuff? if so just search easy mode and if it doesn't come up then it's probably not an option

Answer (score 6):

Samsung provides **Easy Mode** in options (differ from device to device) :

1. Open Settings → Personalisation (by scrolling down) → Easy Mode.

   [image: IMG:]
2. Open Settings → Display → Easy Mode.

   [image: IMG:]

Answer (score 2):

Go to settings > Application Manager > Default Applications > Home Screen > and then change to Easy Mode.

I found this on my GS6, but I think it should work for your phone too.

Answer (score -1):

The **Ultra Energy Saving** mode is the **Easy** mode on this phone.

Comment: How can that be, the salesman showed me this very function on the same model.

Comment: Maybe he showed a Galaxy Core Prime but not a sm-g361f

Comment: So the model I got doesn't have Easy Mode?

Comment: I also bought this model for my parents  (75 and 83 years old with his first smartphone) My mother is using it with normal mode and is going well. My father is waiting to see how my mom is adapted.

Comment: I only changed some icon at the initial screen and the size of letters.

Comment: And waiting for one update with Easy Mode Screen